# CSS performance of using 2 classes versus `extend` when using SASS?

Tags: css, sass

It is common in CSS to create a base class and classes which manipulate the unique values. Font icon libraries are a very common example of this, such as Font Awesome:

```
<i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
```

This makes sense, but when SASS enters the picture you have the ability to use the `extend` feature.

In SASS:

```
%glyph {
  ... stuff ...
}

.glyph-1 {
  @extend %glyph;
  ... unique stuff ...
}

.glyph-2 {
  @extend %glyph;
  ... unique stuff ...
}
```

This results in CSS similar to:

```
.glyph-1, .glyph-2, .glyph-<n> {
  ... contents of %glyph ...
}

.glyph-<number> {
  ... the unique stuff for each <number> ...
}
```

The advantage of this is that I now only need to call `glyph-1` out in my HTML.

The SASS version is more readable and maintainable (IMO) from the development point-of-view, in addition to keeping the HTML "leaner". But the compiled CSS is definitely bulkier (pointless from on the human side, since SASS is being used, but maybe important on the browser side).

Is there a clear performance issue when using one method versus the other, which might skew the preferred method?

Comment: Don't worry about performance until you have a performance problem. Do you? With minimization and gzipping, any size difference is likely to be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

We can think about there being two ways to do this:

- Single class with @extend like your example where you have a type class that includes the base class styles.
- Multiple classes (aka chaining) like in the below example

-

```
.button {}
.button--large {}
.button--primary {}

<button class="button button--large button--primary"></button>
```

The single class way is easy to understand.

The multiple class way is best suited for modules with multiple modifiers that are designed to be mixed and matched. A problem with it, though, is that it is repetitive and you need to be careful of the ordering of the modifier classes.

Another way that combines the benefits of both the previous is to separate the concept of modifier into (variation, modifier and state). So follow something like [this](http://webuild.envato.com/blog/chainable-bem-modifiers/). Where variation is a type, there should be one and you would use extend like your glyph class. Modifier should update some simple property. State would be something like is-disabled.

So we get both benefits:

You can add simple modifiers:

```
<button class="btn -color-red -size-large -shape-round">
```

You can continue to use just the variation classes like in your glyph example.

Comment: That would be the result of poorly written SCSS and improper use of the classes.

Comment: That was a simple example that shows that multiple classes, i.e. chaining, is a possible way of doing it. It's benefit is flexibility.

Comment: I see what you're getting at now; I didn't realize what you were suggesting with the SASS. So this is more a formatting and maintenance preference, versus potential performance? It might be good for generic libraries, but limits classes that are actually descriptive of purpose (e.g., "new-entry" vs. "entry -color-green -corner-round).

Comment: Performance shouldn't make much difference if you are gzipping, so it comes down to a style choice.